# Passing a function down to inner children is not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `DeleteButton` where I am passing `onSubmit` method:

```
  <DeleteButton
    size="tiny"
    key="delete"
    initialValues={this.props.initialValues}
    onSubmit={this.props.dispatchUpdateVariantNote}
    confirmDialog={this.props.deleteConfirm}
  />
```

`onSubmit` function `dispatchUpdateVariantNote` is defined in `mapDispatchToProps` and is the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  dispatchUpdateVariantNote: (updates) => {
    dispatch(updateVariantNote({ ...updates, variant: ownProps.variant, familyGuid: ownProps.familyGuid })) 
  },
})
```

Inside `DeleteButton` I am having another `DispatchRequestButton:

```
const DeleteButton = React.memo(({ initialValues, onSubmit, buttonText, size, ...props }) =>
  <DispatchRequestButton
    onSubmit={() => onSubmit({ ...initialValues, delete: true })} 
    buttonContent={buttonText}
    icon="trash"
    labelPosition={buttonText && 'right'}
    size={size || 'small'}
    {...props}
  />,
)
```

which gets `onSubmit` function: `onSubmit={() => onSubmit({ ...initialValues, delete: true })}`. I verified that all of that happens upon first loading the page: correct functions are present in all of these components. When inside of `DispatchRequestButton` I call `onSubmit()` the result is `undefined` and not the  `dispatchUpdateVariantNote` like I would expect. Why could it happen?

I am using the following versions:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

and `Chrome` browser. The app is launched with local `node.js` server.

Comment: DispatchRequestButton what HTML element will render, a button? why use onSubmit? Did you try without React.memo?

Comment: Whatever the thing you are trying to do here never use `onSubmit` unless you are not submitting a form. It's better if you use `onClick`. Try this out.

Comment: Why `onSubmit` is unacceptable? I need to have a different name because at the very bottom I am calling `onClick` of the button with some other methods including passed `onSubmit`. And yes, I tried without `React.memo`

Comment: I tried changing to `onClick` - the result is the same.